# Save graph as image after click link full script

Tags: chart.js, todataurl

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chart-js/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
            {
                value: 300,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: "Red"
            },
            {
                value: 50,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                label: "Green"
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#FDB45C",
                highlight: "#FFC870",
                label: "Yellow"
            }
        ];

        $(document).ready( 
            function () {
                var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
                var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
                document.getElementById("canvas_link").src = document.getElementById("myChart").toDataURL();                 
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#" id="canvas_link">save as image</a></p>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <p><a href="">export to pdf</a></p>
</body>
```

I need create pdf export and add into image with gener graph. Berofe I must save render image. I try use method .toBase64Image() but I dont know have can I start.

My proceed

create canvas_link (.toDataUrl). After click save as image I can greate and upload image to server. Then I can generate pdf export (across mPDF) and to add imageto into export. This i can create, but I dont know create and upload image of graph to server.

I need more examples from http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Answer (score 4):

in that case you don't need to upload as an image.
you could put the result of the call to toDataUrl function in the value of a hidden field and send it in a form (with an iframe as target) or by an ajax call

use the following options in the chart

```
//new options var
var options = {
    bezierCurve : false,
    //animation: false
    onAnimationComplete: done
};

//your code with a little modification
$(document).ready( 
    function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

        //use the previously defined "options" here!!!
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, options);
    }
);

//callback function, called when the pie ends his animation
function done(){
    //this part of your code was moved here to avoid that store an empty image
    document.getElementById("canvas_link").src = document.getElementById("myChart").toDataURL();

    var postdata={
      file: document.getElementById("myChart").toDataURL()
    }
    $.post( "store.php", postdata)
      .done(function( ret ) {
        console.log( "Data status: Loaded successfully ");
      })
      .fail(function( ret ) {
        console.log( "Data status: error ");
      })
    ;
}
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

in php you can handle the content in this way

```
// file: store.php

// Interpret data uri
$uriPhp = 'data://' . substr($file, 5);
// Get content
$binary = file_get_contents($uriPhp);

$file = 'uploads/charts/'. time() .'.png';

// Save image
file_put_contents($file, $binary);
```

Reference: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/99#issuecomment-75359927

Answer (score -1):

As per the [documentation](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/chart/print/), you can [print](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/chart/print/) or [save](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/chart/export-chart/) graph by API calls;

Example

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    theme: "theme2",
    title:{
        text: "Print Chart using print() method"              
    },
    data: [              
    {
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
            { label: "apple",  y: 10  },
            { label: "orange", y: 15  },
            { label: "banana", y: 25  },
            { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
            { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
        ]
    }
    ]
});

chart.render();
document.getElementById("printChart").addEventListener("click",function(){
    chart.print();
    //chart.exportChart({format: "jpg"});
});
```

Comment: Although the example is good on its own, it refers a different chart library.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't remember when n why I suggested this.